# Convert day/month/year ints to java.time.LocalDate using map

Tags: scala

Given this case classs:

```
case class DateX (year: Int, month: Int, day: Int)
```

And this sequence

```
val dates = Seq(DateX(2001,1,1),DateX(2002,2,2),DateX(2003,3,3))
```

I need to convert the sequence of dates into LocalDate, I tried this but doesn't work:

```
val list = dates.map { x => (x.year, new LocalDate(x.year,x.month,x.day)) }
```

It says that LocalDate does not have a constructor. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. Adjust as needed.

```
dates.map{ case DateX(y,m,d) => java.time.LocalDate.of(y,m,d) }
// res0: Seq[java.time.LocalDate] = List(2001-01-01, 2002-02-02, 2003-03-03)
```